# How often observations occur together in rows R

Tags: r, igraph, plyr, frequency-analysis, chord-diagram

I have a dataframe that is comparable to the one below:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
 A B  C  D  NA NA NA
 A E  F  NA NA NA NA
 D A  C  B  F  E  NA
 A E  NA NA NA NA NA
```

Each row is a patient and each letter in the dataframe represents a specific diagnosis.

I want to find how often specific diagnoses occur together,
e.g. How many times does diagnosis A occur with diagnosis E row-wise? (Three times).

```
I am hoping to produce a matrix like this:
  A B C D E F
A 0 2 2 2 3 2
B 2 0 2
C 2 2 0 etc etc
D 2
E 3
F 2

(I have not completely filled it out)
```

It is essentially an adjacency matrix except that the observations don't need to be directly adjacent, they just need to be on the same row.

From here I would then produce a chorddiagram.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it would be fun to construct this by hand. The algorithm is pretty simple. For each patient find which diagnoses co-occur and write that to an upper triangle matrix.

```
set.seed(357)
xy <- matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:15], size = 80, replace = TRUE), nrow = 8)

> head(xy)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "G"  "F"  "M"  "N"  "D"  "G"  "N"  "H"  "K"  "K"  
[2,] "H"  "I"  "C"  "K"  "H"  "E"  "H"  "E"  "I"  "G"  
[3,] "G"  "C"  "C"  "L"  "N"  "F"  "M"  "K"  "C"  "E"  
[4,] "A"  "K"  "G"  "O"  "I"  "C"  "C"  "B"  "O"  "I"  
[5,] "K"  "O"  "E"  "B"  "M"  "O"  "F"  "C"  "L"  "N"  
[6,] "D"  "H"  "K"  "H"  "I"  "N"  "B"  "F"  "A"  "H" 

# Find all unique diagnoses.
all.diagnoses <- unique(as.vector(xy))
all.diagnoses <- sort(as.character(all.diagnoses))

# This is a way of creating an empty matrix.
out <- matrix(rep(NA, length(all.diagnoses)^2), nrow = length(all.diagnoses),
              dimnames = list(all.diagnoses, all.diagnoses))

for (i in 1:nrow(xy)) {
  combinations <- combn(unique(xy[i, ]), m = 2, simplify = FALSE)
  for (j in 1:length(combinations)) {
    # Add occurrence of each combination to the corresponding combination.
    com <- sort(combinations[[j]])
    out[com[1], com[2]]  <- sum(out[com[1], com[2]], 1, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}

> out
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O
A NA  2  1  2 NA  1  1  1  2  1  3  1  1  2  2
B NA NA  2  1  1  2  1  1  2 NA  3  1  1  2  2
C NA NA NA NA  3  2  3  1  2 NA  4  2  2  2  2
D NA NA NA NA NA  2  1  3  2  2  3  1  3  4  2
E NA NA NA NA NA  2  2  1  1 NA  3  2  2  2  1
F NA NA NA NA NA NA  2  2  1 NA  4  2  3  4  1
G NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  2  2 NA  4  1  2  2  1
H NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  3  1  3 NA  2  3  1
I NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  3 NA  1  2  2
J NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  2  2  2
K NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  3  4  5  3
L NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  3  3  2
M NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  5  3
N NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  3
O NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative approach which uses a *self-join* to create the possible combinations of diagnoses for each patient:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
co_occ_mat <- function(DT) {
  DT[, id := .I] %>% 
    melt("id", na.rm = TRUE, value.name = "diagnosis") %>% 
    unique(by = c("id", "diagnosis")) %>% 
    .[., on = .(id), allow.cartesian = TRUE] %>% 
    .[diagnosis != i.diagnosis] %>% 
    dcast(diagnosis ~ i.diagnosis, length)
}
```

With OP's sample data,  `co_occ_mat()` returns

```
fread("V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
 A B  C  D  NA NA NA
 A E  F  NA NA NA NA
 D A  C  B  F  E  NA
 A E  NA NA NA NA NA") %>% 
  co_occ_mat()
```

> ```
>    diagnosis A B C D E F
> 1:         A 0 2 2 2 3 2
> 2:         B 2 0 2 2 1 1
> 3:         C 2 2 0 2 1 1
> 4:         D 2 2 2 0 1 1
> 5:         E 3 1 1 1 0 2
> 6:         F 2 1 1 1 2 0
> ```

in line with OP's expected result.

The steps in `co_occ_mat()` are:

1. add an `id` column for each row, i.e. patient
2. reshape to long format
3. remove any duplicates in case a diagnosis is reported more than once for a patient
4. create pairs of diagnoses by a cartesian self-join for each `id`
5. remove the trivial cases of pairs where both diagnoses are equal
6. create the co-occurrence matrix by reshaping to wide format and counting the patients

Using the data from [Roman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59509803/3817004)

```
RNGversion("3.6.0")
set.seed(357)
matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:15], size = 80, replace = TRUE), nrow = 8) %>% 
  as.data.table() %T>% print() %>% 
  co_occ_mat()
```

> ```
>    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
> 1:  G  F  M  N  D  G  N  H  K   K
> 2:  H  I  C  K  H  E  H  E  I   G
> 3:  G  C  C  L  N  F  M  K  C   E
> 4:  A  K  G  O  I  C  C  B  O   I
> 5:  K  O  E  B  M  O  F  C  L   N
> 6:  D  H  K  H  I  N  B  F  A   H
> 7:  J  N  D  J  L  K  M  A  O   O
> 8:  J  D  I  M  O  H  N  O  H   H
> ```

we get

> ```
>     diagnosis A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O
>  1:         A 0 2 1 2 0 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 1 2 2
>  2:         B 2 0 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 0 3 1 1 2 2
>  3:         C 1 2 0 0 3 2 3 1 2 0 4 2 2 2 2
>  4:         D 2 1 0 0 0 2 1 3 2 2 3 1 3 4 2
>  5:         E 0 1 3 0 0 2 2 1 1 0 3 2 2 2 1
>  6:         F 1 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 1 0 4 2 3 4 1
>  7:         G 1 1 3 1 2 2 0 2 2 0 4 1 2 2 1
>  8:         H 1 1 1 3 1 2 2 0 3 1 3 0 2 3 1
>  9:         I 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 3 0 1 3 0 1 2 2
> 10:         J 1 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 2 2 2
> 11:         K 3 3 4 3 3 4 4 3 3 1 0 3 4 5 3
> 12:         L 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 0 0 1 3 0 3 3 2
> 13:         M 1 1 2 3 2 3 2 2 1 2 4 3 0 5 3
> 14:         N 2 2 2 4 2 4 2 3 2 2 5 3 5 0 3
> 15:         O 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 3 3 0
> ```

For some reason which I do not understand yet it is required to call `RNGversion("3.6.0")` before `set.seed(357)` in order to reproduce Roman's random numbers.

Note that this test case contains duplicate diagnoses per patient, e.g., `K` in row 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option using `table`:

```
pairs <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
    apply(dat, 1L, function(x) t(combn(na.omit(x), 2L)))))

tab <- table(pairs)
ut <- tab
ut[lower.tri(tab)] <- 0L
lt <- tab
lt[upper.tri(tab)] <- 0L
ans <- t(lt) + ut
ans + t(ans)
```

output:

```
   V1
V2  A B C D E F
  A 0 2 2 2 3 2
  B 2 0 2 2 1 1
  C 2 2 0 2 1 1
  D 2 2 2 0 1 1
  E 3 1 1 1 0 2
  F 2 1 1 1 2 0
```

data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
A B  C  D  NA NA NA
A E  F  NA NA NA NA
D A  C  B  'F'  E  NA
A E  NA NA NA NA NA", header=TRUE, colClasses="character")
```